# Dynamic restructure (wide -> long) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in wide format, here's a simplified version:

[image]

I've restructured it to long format like this (using Tableau add in):

[image]

The thing is, I've had to start over with the restructure every time the table is updated.
My question is if there is a way to create the long format table using formulas so it's dynamic and will update with the data?

**EDIT**
I can't use power-query as suggested in some answers because this is part of a project that's going to sit on a few different computers where I cannot rely on Power-Query being installed/activated. I already created a VBA program to do this before I found out I couldn't use macros in some of the computers where I'll be sending this.  Therefore I really need to do this with good old built-in excel functions only.

The actual data has two more category variables and about 40 more data columns, but the structure is constant, only the data within will be updated.

Comment: see the second answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Comment: can't use power-query - see my edit

Comment: In what way is the example simplified?  For example, can there be more than 3 S columns in the first table?  If the problem is a moving target, this will be outside the intended scope of a question.  Is a VBA solution within your constraints?

Comment: The original data has two more category variables and about 40 more data columns, but the structure is constant, only the data within will be updated. Re VBA - I already created a program to do this before I found out I couldn't use macros in some of the computers where I'll be sending this.

Answer (score 8):

Use PowerQuery to get the result:

[image]

You can refresh directly if you change the data source Table.

Comment: this solution is dynamic indeed but I need to rely on built in excel functions only as this is part of a project i'm sending to a few people and I can't rely of their having PowerQuery  installed/activated.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you found an answer but for anyone else googling this there are some formulas halfway down this page: https://trumpexcel.com/source-data-for-pivot-table/ that can be used instead of Power Query.